# How to return distance result from to points using nearSphere mongodb driver c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this query:

```
await collection.FindAsync(Builders<T>.Filter.NearSphere(s => plcace.Location, location.Longitude, location.Latitude)
& Builders<T>.Filter.Nin(s => s.Id, excludedIDList))
```

which works as expected.

---

However, now I would like to get, in addition to my results, the distance between the given location's point and the documents returned as results.

I tried a couple of approaches such as https://oraerr.com/database/mongodb/c-mongodb-driver-2-0-getting-distance-back-from-near-query/

```
var coll = _database.GetCollection<UrbanEntity>("mycoll");
var geoNearOptions = new BsonDocument {
    { "near", new BsonDocument {
        { "type", "Point" }, 
        { "coordinates", new BsonArray {location.Longitude, location.Latitude} },
        } },
    { "distanceField", "dist.calculated" },
    { "maxDistance", 100 }, 
    { "includeLocs", "dist.location" },  
    { "num", 5 },  
    { "spherical" , true }
};

var pipeline = new List<BsonDocument>();
pipeline.Add( new BsonDocument { {"$geoNear", geoNearOptions} });

using(var cursor = await coll.AggregateAsync<BsonDocument>(pipeline)) {
    while(await cursor.MoveNextAsync()) {
        foreach (var doc in cursor.Current) {
            // Here you have the documents ready to read
        }
    }
}
```

However, (following this code above by example) it returns only 4 documents.. all the time the same ones... I am not sure to understand how does it work. Even if maxDistance line gets removed, I still have the same documents.

Isn't it possible to use `Builders<T>` to build an aggregation instead of `BsonDocument`? Also, how to limit the number of documents returned?

Thanks

Comment: official driver doesn't have a strongly-typed way to get this done. have a look [here](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/tutorial-geospatial-search-in-mongodb-the-easy-way-kbd) for an alternative strongly-typed solution.

Comment: Once it works, I now have the issue that the bson document ain't matching anymore my base class as `dist` isn't a field of the class... Can I set an ouput field such as `dist` but for my entire document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally find what I was looking for (answer slightly edited for ND):

```
public async Task<List<NearbyLocation>> GetNearbyLocationsAsync(Location location, int? take, List<ObjectId> exclude)
{
    var geoNearOptions = new BsonDocument {
        { "near", new BsonDocument {
            { "type", "Point" },
            { "coordinates", new BsonArray { location.Longitude, location.Latitude } }, } },
        { "query", new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument("$nin", new BsonArray(exclude))) }, 
        // "query": Here you can add stuff to your geoNear aggregation. 
        // In fact, when I am searching around, I don't want a couple of IDs.
        { "distanceField", "distance" },
        { "limit", take },
        { "spherical", true}
        // I was first using $nearSphere because of spherical approach.
        // I then set the geoNear query as spherical by setting it to "true".
    };

    var pipeline = new List<BsonDocument>
    {
        new BsonDocument { { "$geoNear", geoNearOptions } },
        new BsonDocument( "$sort", new BsonDocument("distance", 1))
        // As per documentation, $nearSphere is sorting by distance.
        // As per my tests (maybe I am wrong), it wasn't sorted, so I added a sort option
        // to my aggregation.
    };

    List<NearbyLocation> locations = new List<NearbyLocation>();
    using (var cursor = await GetCurrentCollection().AggregateAsync<BsonDocument>(pipeline))
    {
        while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
            {
                double distanceInMeters = doc["distance"].ToDouble();
                NearbyLocation location = new NearbyLocation
                {
                    Location = (BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Location>(doc["location"].ToBson())),
                    KmDistance = distanceInMeters / 1000, // From meters to KMs
                    MileDistance = distanceInMeters * 0.000621371192 // From meters to Miles
                };
                locations.Add(location);
            }
        }
    }

    return locations;
}
```

Lucky me, in my case, the location is a subdocument, which means I just take it and I don't take the whole document, otherwise, I get deserialization error.. still working on it but it's a different issue.

**I so have an issue regarding the deserialization as the `distance` field is actually not part of my class.. I am then looking now into put my resulted document into another field such as:**

```
{
    "distance":0.1234,
    "location":{...}
}
```